# mwoffliner ZIM file creation issue with local MediaWiki

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments, mediawiki, zim

I installed mwoffliner 1.6.0 as per [these instructions](https://github.com/openzim/mwoffliner) in a Ubuntu 18.10 (cosmic, desktop edition). Some programs were missing and I apparently managed to install all of them.

I succeeded running the command-line and download an external Wiki (namely ts.wikipedia.org), however when I tried to download my local wiki (hosted locally, inside Ubuntu 18.10) it ended in utter failure. Find here below the command line I issued:
`mwoffliner --mwUrl=http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc --adminEmail=foo@bar.net --verbose --redis=redis://127.0.0.1:6379 --mwWikiPath=/ --mwApiPath=api.php`

According to the error report, it is `zimwriterfs` (invoked by `mwoffliner`) that fails to find the `welcome page at '`. It seems it is looking for a `Main_Page.html`, whereas the wiki only has a `Main_Page`. I tried typing `Main_Page.html` (as in `http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/index.php/Main_Page.html` instead of `http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/index.php/Main_Page`) but the wiki does not find it.

I don't know how to give `zimwriterfs` a `--welcome=Main_Page` argument instead of the `--welcome=Main_Page.html` that appears in the error output. As a matter of fact, if one looks at the code sent to `zimwriterfs` there are 2 `--welcome=` arguments which seems odd and contradictory. Find here below the end of the output given by `--verbose` (I put the end of the output where the errors start but it might be that only the very end is relevant in this case).

Any ideas on how to solve this one would be much appreciated.

```
Create main page redirection...
Saving articles...
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Main_Page&oldid=68
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Main_Page&oldid=68...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT&oldid=69
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT&oldid=69...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT&oldid=69 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/6a89ec3991120c028d52...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Procedures&oldid=70
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Procedures&oldid=70...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Procedures&oldid=70 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/e222c242065891deecb2...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Apple&oldid=94
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Apple&oldid=94...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Apple&oldid=94 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/8974a0b093782a04efea...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=AS_Server&oldid=79
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=AS_Server&oldid=79...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=AS_Server&oldid=79 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/9cf768ef56612ddd8cd7...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ASL_Server&oldid=89
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ASL_Server&oldid=89...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ASL_Server&oldid=89 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/c0b5e21df4c78b2fb7f6...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Additional_Restricted_or_Tools_Software_Installation&oldid=87
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Additional_Restricted_or_Tools_Software_Installation&oldid=87...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Additional_Restricted_or_Tools_Software_Installation&oldid=87 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/54e0ea0e4ef2e50a1c51...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ICRC_WAN_to_Connect_WAN_Migration&oldid=51
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ICRC_WAN_to_Connect_WAN_Migration&oldid=51...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=ICRC_WAN_to_Connect_WAN_Migration&oldid=51 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/4ef68e32b02ffd66d731...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network_Installation&oldid=85
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network_Installation&oldid=85...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network_Installation&oldid=85 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/816eddcf9574bcca187f...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Peripheral_Installation&oldid=78
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Peripheral_Installation&oldid=78...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Peripheral_Installation&oldid=78 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/b4e70d7a3187dc0fa857...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Site_Migration&oldid=80
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Site_Migration&oldid=80...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Site_Migration&oldid=80 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/d4fb71c124eb9cedbd02...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Unified_Workstation&oldid=32
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Unified_Workstation&oldid=32...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Unified_Workstation&oldid=32 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/f8dec06be846056ae4e8...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Virus_infection_and_DRP_Infrastructure_Recover&oldid=81
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Virus_infection_and_DRP_Infrastructure_Recover&oldid=81...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Virus_infection_and_DRP_Infrastructure_Recover&oldid=81 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/b2f1f1ce29172b75e9c6...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Xtended_Storage&oldid=33
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Xtended_Storage&oldid=33...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Xtended_Storage&oldid=33 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/17b3845e62854eb06a89...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Standards&oldid=34
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Standards&oldid=34...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IT_Standards&oldid=34 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/b4476cde1f4c51aa7f0c...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Baseline&oldid=82
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Baseline&oldid=82...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Baseline&oldid=82 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/5f118fff319e794f5ccf...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network&oldid=90
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network&oldid=90...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Network&oldid=90 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/7237405ef5efd9b1caad...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Telecom&oldid=92
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Telecom&oldid=92...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Telecom&oldid=92 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/02acdad51aa3a5b34331...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Other_Standards&oldid=91
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Other_Standards&oldid=91...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Other_Standards&oldid=91 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/03fdafacd18212177c2b...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About&oldid=97
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About&oldid=97...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About&oldid=97 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/4c1555b04b0ccd1a1520...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Managed_Switches&oldid=46
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Managed_Switches&oldid=46...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Managed_Switches&oldid=46 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/e1c0d8a7e3b95f948582...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About-Collapsible&oldid=150
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About-Collapsible&oldid=150...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=IMac-About-Collapsible&oldid=150 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/1ecadf62e667dee7d064...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
Getting (desktop) article from http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Cisco_Aironet_1300_Series_Outdoor_Wireless_Bridge&oldid=148
Downloading http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Cisco_Aironet_1300_Series_Outdoor_Wireless_Bridge&oldid=148...
Caching http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=Cisco_Aironet_1300_Series_Outdoor_Wireless_Bridge&oldid=148 at /home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/e13201f13a1089b452c7...
Error by retrieving article: Unrecognized value for parameter "action": visualeditor.
All articles were retrieved and saved.
0 files still to be downloaded.
Process still downloading images...
All images successfuly downloaded
0 images still to be optimized.
Process still optimizing images...
All images successfuly optimized
Building ZIM file /home/pit/Downloads/out/192_en_all_2019-01.zim (zimwriterfs --welcome=index.htm --favicon=favicon.png --language=eng --welcome=Main_Page.html --verbose  --tags="56" --name="kiwix.192_en_all" --redirects="/home/pit/Downloads/cac/192_en/192_en_all.redirects" --title="Unified ICT Doc" --description="From Unified ICT Doc" --creator="192" --publisher="Kiwix" "/home/pit/Downloads/tmp/192_en_all_2019-01/" "/home/pit/Downloads/out/192_en_all_2019-01.zim")...
RAID: kiwix.192_en_all
zimwriterfs: unable to find welcome page at '
/home/pit/Downloads/tmp/192_en_all_2019-01
/
Main_Page.html
'. --welcome path/value must be relative to HTML_DIRECTORY.

Failed to run mwoffliner after [105s]: "Failed to build successfuly the ZIM file /home/pit/Downloads/out/192_en_all_2019-01.zim (Error when executing zimwriterfs)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the argument `--localParsoid` solved the problem. So the entire command looks now like as follows:

`mwoffliner --mwUrl=http://192.168.56.5/UnifiedICTDoc --adminEmail=foo@bar.net --verbose --redis=redis://127.0.0.1:6379 --mwWikiPath=/ --mwApiPath=api.php --localParsoid`

Comment: Although the ZIM file is now created and can be imported in Kiwix, problems still persist. Namely not all the page have been created by `mwoffliner`. But that is another issue.